# excluding delimiters from csv.Sniffer()

Tags: python, csv

As a part of a script, I am reading a file without the user specifying the delimiter.
Theoretically, I want to be able to use this script for any type of delimiter besides some specific ones.

Is there a way to tell csv.Sniffer() "These characters are not delimiters:..." ?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) I saw that there's an optional argument for specifying valid delimiters but that's not what I'm looking for.

As it seem, this option is not supported - let me know if I am wrong or that there is another module that provides the same functionality.

Comment: Try to use pandas for csv read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Do you refer to the `dialect` argument? because it is  a `csv.Dialect` object and it doesn't seem to help.
Could you elaborate more on what did you mean by using this funciton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to specify that characters *aren't* delimiters in the existing `Sniffer` implementation..

Delimiters are identified in the [Sniffer._guess_quote_and_delimiter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ff6975e2c0af0399467f234b2e307cc76efcfa9/Lib/csv.py#L204) and [Sniffer._guess_delimiters](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ff6975e2c0af0399467f234b2e307cc76efcfa9/Lib/csv.py#L280) methods.

To negatively specify delimiters you would need to subclass `Sniffer` and override these methods to take into account the set of "not allowed" delimiter characters.